# permission denied trying to read a csv file using JDBC for postgres database

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I  am trying to make a program which calculates time elapsed for executing a query in postgres.I am using JDBC for this purpose. I am bulk loading a file data.csv using the

```
copy
```

statement. When I try n execute the command

```
copy data_1 from 'C:\\Users\\Abhishek\\Desktop\\data1.csv' using delimiters ','"
```

using the cmd prompt,It executes. But when I try n execute the same command using java and JDBC.. it gives the error that

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open file for reading: Permission denied
```

How can I change the permission on the file so that I can help my jre to get to use that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you execute the statement as **superuser** in psql and as another user via JDBC?
The [manual tells us](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html):

> COPY naming a file is only allowed to database superusers, since it
>   allows reading or writing any file that the server has privileges to
>   access.

You *can* circumvent this restriction by wrapping the statement in a function with [`SECURITY DEFINER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) owned by a superuser. Be aware of the [security risks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY). You may also want to [REVOKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-revoke.html) all rights from public and only [GRANT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html) to selected users. Could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
    COPY data_1
    FROM E'C:\\Users\\Abhishek\\Desktop\\data1.csv'
    USING delimiters ',';
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  SET search_path = public, pg_temp;  -- or whatever schema the table is in

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION foo() FROM public;
GRANT SELECT ON FUNCTION foo() TO my_user;
```

---

Also, be aware that [the proper syntax for escape strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE) is:

```
E'C:\\Users\\Abhishek\\Desktop\\data1.csv'
```

Note the `E'...'`.
As of version 9.1, the setting `standard_conforming_strings` is on by default, enforcing this.

Comment: I was originally doing it as a superuser only.. But even that did not help. Finally to complete the assignment.. I did it on my linux platform. Seems it was simple permission issue. I got it done there by making permission of the file global using chmod.

Comment: @abhiitd.cs: Only give file permissions to the postgres system user. That's all it takes. Doesn't have to be world-readable.

Answer (score 1):

For one-time, bulk loads from a file, it can be easier to toggle permissions on the *file*, rather than mess with the permissions of the Windows and PostgreSQL users.

Right clicking on the folder containing the file(s), then under "security", give "everyone" permission to read the file. When done, remove the "everyone" permissions. This can also be followed to make a folder the "write" destination when dumping data from PostgreSQL on Windows.

A step-by-step guide is given in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486389/3003133).