# COPY FROM CSV to Postgres in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, csv, import, postgresql-9.1

My question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14083311/1777654) but in Linux Mint 15 (Ubuntu). I've tried the standard [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) (which I used on Windows all the time):

`COPY public.bio FROM 'tmp/sisinst_bio.csv' 
DELIMITERS '|' CSV;`

I receive this error:

`ERROR: could not open file "/tmp/sisinst_bio.csv" for reading: Permission denied`

The owner and user of the database is `postgres`.

**Tries**

(1) Creating a user that is the same as my user account for Ubuntu (`zach`) and changing the owner of the database.

(2) Moving the csv to various parts of Ubuntu

`sudo cp -r /home/zach/Documents/Postgres91/sisinst_postgresql_bio_test.csv /usr/share/postgresql/9.1`

`sudo cp -r /home/zach/Documents/Postgres91/sisinst_postgresql_bio_test.csv /tmp`

This is really easy but I'm stuck. I'm not sure if this is `Postgresql` or `Ubuntu` problem.

**Update**

Does this have anything to do with [this](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/c939097c0604181058r790128c6ge87654af630ce9a5@mail.gmail.com)?

As always, thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `Permissions` in the `CSV` (`Right Click` -> `Properties` -> `Permissions`), the `Others` was set to `None`.

To fix this so that `Postgres` users can use it, I changed `Others` to `Read-only` which worked.

Ultimately, it might be better have `Postgres` users in a `Group` but that's above me at this point.

I'm open to a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ls -l /tmp/sisinst_bio.csv` to see what the permissions on the file are.  Chances are you'll see something like `-rw-------`, which means it's readable and writeable by the owner, but not readable by anyone else.

If that's the case, try making the CSV file group- and world-readable, using:

```
chmod g+r,o+r /tmp/sisinst_bio.csv
```

Comment: you're right on the `-rw-------` but `chmod g+r,o+r /tmp/sisinst_bio.csv` gave me this error: <br> `chmod: changing permissions of ‘/tmp/sisinst_bio.csv’: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: First, don't connect to Postgres as postgres unless performing initial setup admin. Second, chown the file to whatever user you are connecting as. If you can't chown or chmod the file, you may have to sudo chown, or copy it to a new location that you can control (if Mint 15 has a special trapping mechanism for /tmp -- which may be the case).

Comment: Ok, I've changed the ownership of the file using [chown](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/). I'm also using a new user in Postgres (`zach`). I run `ls -l /home/zach/Documents/Postgres91/sisinst_bio.csv`. The file is owned in this way: `-rw-rw---- 1 zach zach 90722 may 30 12:39` and I'm still receiving the same error in `Postgres`. Does this mean that it is owned by the user `zach` and group `zach`?

Comment: Yes - this means it's owned by user `zach` and group `zach`.  `-rw-rw----` means it's readable and writable by the owning user, and by any user in the owning group.   `chmod` should now work.  `chmod o+r /home/zach/Documents/Postgres91/sisinst_bio.csv` will make it readable by any user.

Comment: I should probably clarify:  Postgres users and UNIX users are not the same thing.  When you do a `COPY`, the copy runs on the server as whatever Unix user the server is running as.  That's why even though you have a Unix user named "zach" and a Postgres user named "zach", you still can't access the file.  Making the file readable by any user will ensure the Pg server can read it.  The alternative is to make the file owned by the Pg server user.