# Permission denied on postgres COPY FROM but folders have read permissions

Tags: postgresql, redhat, pgadmin

Running Postgres 9.2 on `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)`. Communicating with the server using `PGAdmin III`.

I'm trying to `COPY FROM` a CSV file at `/home/foo_user/dir/bar.csv` but get:

```
could not open file "/home/foo_user/dir/bar.csv" for reading: Permission denied
```

[Running `sudo setenforce 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12277934/2071807) via SSH returns

```
setenforce: SELinux is disabled
```

but doesn't resolve the problem.

[As per this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16847039/2071807), permissions on the file are `-rwxrwxrwx` (overkill, I know, but just in case!). The containing folder `/home/foo_user` has `drwxr--r--` and subfolder `dir` has `drwxr--r--`.

So it's not permissions, and it's not `SELinux`. What's left to try? (I'm assuming I don't have to restart the postgres service after any of these changes, but maybe that's not right?)

Answer (score 3):

Oops. Permissions are *not* OK! Folders need execute permissions to allow their contents to be read. Thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened) for the tip-off.

This was fixed with

```
chmod o+x /home/foo_user
chmod o+x /home/foo_user/dir
```

to add execute permissions for "everyone" (the 'other' user for `chmod`)

In summary, all directories must have at least `-rwx---r-x` (read and execute for 'other') and the file itself must have at least `-rwx---rw-` (read and write for 'other').