# Unable to copy cvs data to postgresql table

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have tried reffering to the questions asked in SO

in my sql i have written :

```
COPY lcities FROM E'C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\sneh.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "Lawyer Code, Lawyer Name, Years of Experience, Location, Average Rating"
CONTEXT:  COPY lcities, line 1, column id: "Lawyer Code, Lawyer Name, Years of Experience, Location, Average Rating"

********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "Lawyer Code, Lawyer Name, Years of Experience, Location, Average Rating"
SQL state: 22P02
Context: COPY lcities, line 1, column id: "Lawyer Code, Lawyer Name, Years of Experience, Location, Average Rating"
```

Comment: What's unclear about "*relation "sneh" does not exist*"?

Comment: Surely that's pretty self explanatory. There is no table named `sneh`. (Are you perhaps being confused by case folding? Is there a table named `"SNEH"` - note the double quotes ?)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14083542/1216680

Answer (score 1):

ok this **ERROR:  relation "sneh" does not exist** tell you to your PostgreSQL table **sneh** does not exist.

You first create **sneh** name table inside **PostgreSQL** and try again. But be clear when you **create table** at that time **take care** for which **datatype** you can use. Because this would be create error, the reason behind **conflict datatype** from **CSV data** or your **PostgreSQL** Column **Data type**.

---

And your Path i think not **navigate** to your **destination location** Update this **2 time backward Slash** to a **Forward Slash**.

```
C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/sneh.csv
```

---

**Update Permission via Command Prompt**

```
chmod a+rX  C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/sneh.csv
```

This will change access rights for your folder. Now everyone will be able to read your file.

**Update Permission via My Computer**

- Right click the `Desktop` folder containing the data file(s) that permission was denied to and then click **Properties**.
- Select the **Security** tab.
- Click the **Edit** button.
- In the **"Permissions for the folder"** window that opened, click the **Add** button.
- Type `Everyone` into the **"Enter the object names to select"** text area box.
- Click **OK** and the window will close.
- Verify that the default **Read & Execute** permissions were set to **Allow** via the check checkbox in the previous window.
- Click **OK** and the window will **close**.
- Click the **Apply** button in the Folder Properties window.

Hope this help you!

Comment: i have changed it to my table in postgresql , now it shows mw that unable to read

Comment: `COPY lcities FROM E'chomod a+rX C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/sneh.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV
` am i correnct ?

Comment: no you first give permission to that folder via Command Prompt or My Computer.

Comment: you can ask another question on here. Do not modify this question. And  if this answer help you then accept.

Comment: Windows doesn't have `chmod`. Also as far as I know Windows doesn't use the "execute" bit on directories as "may traverse the dir" like 'nix does, though I'm unsure of that bit.