# Error Exporting .csv from PostgreSQL using Python 3

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have a simple PostgreSQL `copy` statement that copies a table from a network host (NETWORK-HOST) database to a .csv file on a shared network folder. It works fine in PGAdmin, but when I transfer it to a psycopg2 script, it tells me `permission denied`. I have double checked to make sure full control is granted to my username on the network share, but that has not made a difference. I am running Windows 10, Python 3 (32 bit), PostgreSQL 9.5.1.

Here is the script in PGAdmin that runs successfully:

```
copy "Schema".county_check_audit to '\\NETWORK-HOST\NetworkFolder\county_check.csv' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER;
```

here is the script where I get the permission error:

```
import psycopg2
connection = psycopg2.connect(database="db", user="postgres", password="password", host="NETWORK-HOST")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("copy \"Schema\".area_check_audit to '\\\\NETWORK-HOST\\NetworkFolder\\area_check.csv' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER;")
connection.commit()
```

This is the error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: could not open file "\\NETWORK-HOST\NetworkFolder\area_check.csv" for writing: Permission denied
```

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: according to the error message, you have to add write access to the file (to the user that is executing you py script i guess) . I'd suggest to test your code first by trying to write to a file that is on the same host and once you are sure your code is fine, you can debug the access rights to your file on another host.

Comment: It appears I am getting the same error when I try to export a table from my localhost to my C: drive so there must be a problem with my code.

Comment: you have to change your file's security access as mentioned in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486389/1360584

Comment: you were correct, except I needed to add the 'write' permissions as well as the 'read' permissions in the settings.

Comment: @AkliREGUIG if you want to add this as an answer I will give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, you have to add write access to the file.

To change file'security access on windows, check : [Permission denied when trying to import a CSV file from PGAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083311/permission-denied-when-trying-to-import-a-csv-file-from-pgadmin/22486389#22486389)

I'd suggest to test your code first by trying to write to a file that is on the same host and once you are sure your code is fine, you can debug the access rights to your file on another host.