# Can't import CSV PostgreSQL Windows 10

Tags: windows, postgresql

```
COPY test
FROM 'C:\Users\micro\Downloads\test.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

I have shared the download directory (right click, properties etc.) and I get this error:

```
ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Users\micro\Downloads\test.csv" for reading: 
Permission denied
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You 
may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
SQL state: 42501
```

Using "\COPY" gives a syntax error

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied when trying to import a CSV file from PGAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083311/permission-denied-when-trying-to-import-a-csv-file-from-pgadmin)

Comment: thank you, there was a link to permissioning folders in your suggested question.

Comment: Solved: see JGH's comment. Specifically this link in the related question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754344(v=ws.11)

Comment: In this thread you can find the answer: <https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29767/permission-denied-in-file-trying-to-import>

Comment: Take a look at this: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486389>
It solved the problem for me.